# Is angular fire support PhoneAuthProvider and linkWithCredentials?

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I saw firebase documentation there is PhoneAuthProvider and linkWithCredentials, but I not sure is angular fire can did it. I checked angular fire github documentation but there is not writing about it.

Comment: AngularFire is essentially a wrapper of the [Firebase JavaScript SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js), hence you should be able to use phone authentication.

Comment: I tried to call linkWithCredentials from authState.auth.linkWithCredentials, but it is not available, authState is reference from { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';

Comment: What version of AngularFire are you using?

Comment: "@angular/fire": "^5.4.2"